# Model Property Value having Space not mapping Correctly In Razor View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a property FirstName in a employee model, the value of the FirstName is bilal khan, when i fetch the data and map it to html tags it parsed incorrectly after space word is not mapping.

```
public Class Employee
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
}
//set employee FirstName="Bilal Khan"
```

I have strongly type view bind with employee class

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li id=@item.ChatDialogID class="person"  data-chat-recievername=@item.RecieverDisplayName>
}
```

**Browser output**

when i do inspect element above information display in the browser like

```
<li id="1" class="person active" data-chat="1" data-chat-sender="15" data-chat-reciever="20080" data-chat-recievername="bilal" khan="">
```

as you can see that it takes the first word and not the second one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to surround the attribute values in quotes

```
<li id="@item.ChatDialogID" class="person" data-chat-recievername="@item.RecieverDisplayName">
```

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider accepting it (and the answers to your other questions that worked for you) - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: thanks for sharing the information i was under the impression you have already too much reputation :p

Comment: It has nothing to do with reputation. Its about indicating to others that the answer works (or are you under the impression  that this site was developed for you personally)

Comment: Thanks @stephen Muecke Sorry i was considering the only one side of the picture.